# How to generate all numbers randomly in the limit [m,n] in matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, numbers, limit

How to generate all numbers randomly in the `limit [m,n]`. To generate all numbers from `6 to 12`.. ie., the sequence must be like `[7 12 11 9 8 10 6]`.

```
r = randi([6 12],1,7);
```

But this gives the result:

```
[12  11  12   7   9  10  12]
```

Here the numbers are repeated and the sequence does not contain all numbers from `6 to 12`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `randperm` to make a list of random numbers between 1 and `n` (where `n` is the length of your vector), and use that to permute the vector.

```
v=6:12;
n=length(v);
I=randperm(n);
v(I)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are sampling using a uniform distribution.

`r = datasample(6:12,7,'Replace',false)`

In a nutshell this does a random sampling without replacement, hence you get all the values from your original population in a random order.

Comment: Minor note: This requires the Statistics Toolbox.  The accepted answer provides better compatibility as it relies on no toolboxes.